# Running a bash script with an infinite while loop at startup and in the background on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I've made a small bash script that I want to run on startup of my Raspberry Pi. I would like this script to run constantly on the machine because I have a mounted USB drive that keeps disconnecting at random times. I use it for media storage and would like to find out at what times it's disconnecting and then remount the drive.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
while : 
do 
if mountpoint -q /media/Media
then
    continue
else
    echo $(date) >> log.txt
    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/Media
fi
sleep 1
done
```

Basically I would like this to run when the Raspberry Pi boots and have it continuously running in the background at all times.

Can anyone give me some help doing this? Thank you.

Comment: When the USB drive disconnects, does it trigger any udev rules? Does it write something to /var/log/messages (or equivalent file)? If yes, I would suggest you to use those (trigger based) mechanisms instead of polling.

Comment: It looks like there may be something showing up in /var/log/daemon.log. What sort of trigger based mechanism in bash could I use? I'd still need to have it monitoring that file in order to know when to remount the drive automatically, no? Forgive me if I'm ignorant. I'm quite new to writing Linux bash scripts.

Comment: `tail -f  /var/log/messages | grep --line-buffered "whatever that gets printed on unmount" | while read x; do sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/Media; done`

Comment: Actually inotifywait supports unmount option... Adding as answer... See if your distro running on raspberry pi has this package or if you can add it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)

```
sudo inotifywait -d -e unmount /media/Media/some_file | while read unmounted; do 
    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/Media
done
```

Or maybe:

```
while true; do
    sudo inotifywait -e unmount /media/Media/some_file | read unmounted
    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/Media
done
```

Comment: That is a great way of making what I was trying to do better, and thank you or that, but how do I run it at startup and in the background?

Comment: startup: `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/init.d` background: `&`